# Django: Replacing form field with another form

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a simple way to replace a form field in Django with another form? Specifically, I have a one-to-one relationship between two models, and it would be great if I could define a field to actually be defined as another form, something like this:

```
class FirstModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FirstModel

class SecondModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    second = forms.InnerForm(form=FirstModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
```

Any ideas? Or should I write it myself and submit to Django codebase? ;-)

Comment: Why [Model FormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) is not a solution for you?

Comment: Because it's a one-to-one field, not a foreign key; basically it's another model field, only more complex, enough to be an object in its own right. I don't need several instances of a form, just one but at a certain place in the parent form.

As I was writing this question I have realized that it's more of a feature request than a question as such. :-)

Comment: I htink you better use model inheritance, which is basically one-to-one relationship. Then the form will adapt autmatically